# LightningConsole Permset License in Scratch Org

Tags: permission-sets, scratch-org, scratch-org-definition-file, permission-set-licenses

Does anybody know how to enable the LightningConsole Permset License in Scratch orgs?

I've added `LightningSalesConsole` and `LightningServiceConsole` to features in the scratch org def file but it didn't work.